# Exit from BASH Infinite loop in a pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I encountered a somewhat strange behavior of BASH infinite loops which outputs are pipelined to another processes. Namely, I run these two commands:

```
(while true; do echo xxx; done) | head -n 1
(while true; do date; done) | head -n 1
```

The first one exits instantly while the second one does not (and I assume it would run forever without being killed). I also tried an implicit infinite loop:

```
yes | head -n 1
```

and it also exits by itself. An appropriate line of output is immediately printed on the screen in each case. I am just curious what determines if such a commmand will finish.

Comment: Note that the parentheses are unnecessary; a `while` loop is a complete command in its own right which can be the left-hand side of a pipeline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When `head` exits, the standard output of the parenthesized expression is closed. If an external command, like `date`, is used, the loop hangs. If an internal command of bash is used, like `echo`, the loop exits. For proof, use

```
(while true; do /bin/echo xxx; done) | head -n 1
```

and it will hang. If you use

```
(while true; do date; echo $? 1>&2; sleep 1; done) | head -n 1
```

you will see that on the second round, the `date` command returns an error exit code, i.e. something other but zero. Bash obviously does this not take as serious as when an internal command gets into problems. I wonder if this is intended or rather a bug in bash.

To make sure the loop is exited, this seems to work:

```
(set -e; while true; do date ; done) | head -n 1
```

Comment: The only process that exits is the one that tries to write to the closed file handle left behind when `head` exits. When the external program `date` is the "victim", the `bash` shell will continue, constantly spawning `date` processes which try to write and receive `SIGPIPE`. With the builtin, it's the `bash` shell itself that receives `SIGPIPE`, and so it exits, terminating the pipeline.

Comment: `set -e` works because, when `date` tries to write to the closed file handle the first time, it exits with non-zero status, which causes the `bash` shell running the while loop to exit as well in accordance with the `-e` option.